# Unable to create Easy Tables in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have created a Mobile App and Database in Microsoft Azure. Now I am trying to create Easy Tables from Mobile App but I am getting error message "You need database to use East Tables. Click here to create one.

Even though I have  existing database Easy Tables doesn't list it.

Below is the screenshot.

[image]

I have mapped Data Connection with mobile app, below is the screenshot

[image]

It would be great if anyone can help, I am new to azure.

Answer (score 9):

Your connection string must be created with name: MS_TableConnectionString

Answer (score 3):

Just because you have a database doesn't mean it is linked.  Click on Data Connections, then Add, then add your existing SQL database.

Note that Easy Tables won't recognize the existing tables unless you add them through Easy Tables.  There are notes around the format of Id (it needs to be
a string) and other fields.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for responding, I have updated my question with more information! I have mapped Data Connection with mobile app but it doesn't show up in Easy Tables

Comment: The table connection string must be called MS_TableConnectionString - nothing else will work.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, problem solved. It would have been great if in Portal it would have been mentioned that "MS_TableConnectionString" needs to be connection string.

Comment: Stupid Azure... I've wasted 2 hours of my time just because AZURE was not able to tell me YOU SHOULDN'T CHANGE THE CONNECTION STRING NAME...

Answer (score 1):

When you created your Database Server did you check "Allow azure services to access server"? That could be why you cannot see the Database listed.

Comment: Thanks Sal, where can i check that?